# How to pass increase <td id>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and i am cloning rows to add a new row. My `<td id>` is also increasing. My problem is though the value of each `<td id>` is increasing when the value is passing from one screen to the next screen the `<td id>` will be like this

`<flddesc>`Val1`<flddesc>`

`<flddesc>`Val2`<flddesc>`

I have tried couple of things but no luck And now i have no idea why is it so. Since i am still learning jQuery and JS so please go easy on me. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
var cindex = 0;
var counter = 0;
var quicklink = '';
$(document).on('click', '.Buttons', function(addrow) {
  if (counter == '5') {
    alert('Maximum limit reached');
    return false;
  }
  var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_, el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;

  if (count || !$('.id_100 option[value=description]').attr('selected', 'selected')) {
    {
      alert("Please fill the current row");
      return false;
    }
  }

  var $tr = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
  var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
  $('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
  cindex++;
  $clone.find('input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
  $clone.find('input:button').attr('disabled', true);
  $clone.attr('id', 'id' + (cindex)); //update row id if required
  //update ids of elements in row
  $clone.find("*").each(function() {
    var id = this.id || "";
    if (id != "") {

      var match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 2) {
        this.id = this.name + (cindex);
      }
    }
  });
  $tr.after($clone);
  counter++;

});

function disableField(e)
{ var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
    if (Count == 2){
 $(e).closest('tr').find("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
        
    }else{
 $(e).closest('tr').find("input").prop('disabled', false);
}}

 $(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 
  counter--;
  var Count1 = $('#dataTable tr').length;
  if (Count1 == 2){
  $('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">

      <td>
        <div class="id_100">
          <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="L">Latest Offer</option>
             <option value="G">Guides</option>
          
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="45" value="" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="55" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="40" value="" />

      </td>
      <td>
        <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton" type="button" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button5" value="Initiate" class="buttons" name="Button5" type="button" onclick="return fnOnSubmit();"/></li>
     

  </ul>
 
</div>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.Buttons', function(addrow) { ...` There is no element with the `Buttons` class.

Comment: Sorry my bad i forgot to add the ```HTML``` code for button. I have added now.

Comment: Is there any other code you might have left out? Because I can't enter text into your fields.

Comment: Check again please.

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you even need the `id` on the `input` when you know they are not unique? I would remove them, no hassle in keeping them unique.

Comment: @Titulum so i am increasing my ```<td id>``` when i am cloning it. I need to pass the values of this table to next screen. When i am checking the values on next screen the values remain under the same ```<td id>``` and not increased ```<td id>```. Like this 1) ```<flddesc>Val1</flddesc>``` and 2) ```<flddesc>Val2</flddesc>```

Comment: @nathanvda i am using id to distinguish my different values of different ```<td>``` so as to handle it properly on next screen as the next screen is review screen so the value should retain in there corresponding fields and when the user wants to modify any values the values remain in there corresponding field in the first screen.

Comment: I don't see any IDs on your TDs. Your inputs have IDs, though, and they seem to be incrementing correctly.

Comment: Yes exactly but when i am checking on the second screen there in no increase ID which contains value instead it just the normal ```<td>``` which contains all the values in different tags.

Comment: Without seeing this "second screen," this is hard to troubleshoot. Looking at the code you've provided, I don't see anything that would apply an ID to any `<td>` elements.